# Remove all the occurrences of a term in a list

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I am trying to remove the United States listed in the organization columns within a list for all the rows of an extensive dataset.

My df looks something like this:

| ID | Organizations |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['education', 'health', 'United States', 'facebook'] |
| 2 | ['health', 'Airlines', 'WHO', 'United States'] |

...

I want my output to look like this:

| ID | Organizations |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['education', 'health','facebook'] |
| 2 | ['health', 'Airlines', 'WHO'] |

The code I tried:

```
df=df['organizations'].remove("United States")
```

gave me the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'remove'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to loop here, using `apply`:

```
df['Organizations'].apply(lambda l: l.remove('United States'))
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
df['Organizations'] = [[x for x in l if x != 'United States'] for l in df['Organizations']]
```

Output:

```
   ID                  Organizations
0   1  [education, health, facebook]
1   2        [health, Airlines, WHO]
```

*Note that the first one will fail if you don't have 'United States' in all the lists*

##### handling NaNs

```
df['Organizations'] = [[x for x in l if x != 'United States']
                       if isinstance(l, list) else l
                       for l in df['Organizations']]
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2], 
                   'Organizations': [['education', 'health', 'United States', 'facebook'],
                                     ['health', 'Airlines', 'WHO', 'United States']]})
```

Comment: First code one is giving me: 'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable', and the second code gives me: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'  - @mozway

Comment: Do you have 'NaNs` in your column? Check the update

Comment: I removed NaNs and getting the same error - @mozway

Comment: Then your dataset is not what you described. You likely have strings, not lists. Please provide a reproducible input: `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: I provided reproducible input. Now it says: "Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead" for both `df['Organizations'] = [[x for x in l if x != 'United States'] if isinstance(l, list) else l for l in df['Organizations']]`  and `df['Organizations'] = [[x for x in l if x != 'United States'] for l in df['Organizations']]` Should I make a .copy()? - @mozway

Comment: I don't see the reproducible input, make sure to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72525549/edit) your question

Comment: And the warning you got is likely not directly related to this question. Check SettingWithCopyWarning on this site to see how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider:

```
(df.explode('Organizations')
  .query('Organizations != "United States"').groupby('ID')
  .agg(list).reset_index())

   ID                  Organizations
0   1  [education, health, facebook]
1   2        [health, Airlines, WHO]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to explode, drop the values, then aggregate back with `groupby`:

```
df['Organizations'] = df['Organizations'].explode()\
   .loc[lambda x: x!='United States']]\
   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: But I expect this to be as lot slower than a list comprehension ;)

Comment: You may be correct, may be not. I can’t test this atm, but I did remember seeing this being faster than list comprehension at some point. I can’t recall the exact operation, but it was also some string manipulation.

Comment: For sure we would need to test on real data. Every time it tested `explode` in similar cases that was slower, so I'd be interested in this example if your remember it!